# Removing old symbolic links in clearcase

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

Using:

```
cleartool find . -kind slink -print
```

Shows me symbolic links in my vob

However, the folder no longer exists, and it requires me to check out the parent folder to rmname the link.

Any advice, on how I can remove this symbolic link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to use is [`cleartool rmname -nco`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmname.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.1%2F9-0-0-1-59):

> To remove a name from a checked-in directory version, you can use the `-nco` option.
>   For example, you may want to remove an old symbolic link that points to a file that has been removed.

```
-nco
```

> Prompts for confirmation (unless used with `-force`), then removes the name or link from the checked-in directory version that you specify.

That means if you want to remove *all* symlinks found, you could combine find + exec (**use with cautious**, at least without the `-force` at first):

```
cleartool find . -kind slink -exec "cleartool rmname -nco -force \"%CLEARTOOL_XPN%\""
```